# Get key's values which are common in two hashes using perl

Tags: perl

I want to create a hash which contains key's values which are common in two hashes. In the below code, "test1" is available in two hashes values. Hence get the key value of both hashes, store it in array and create a new hash

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array1 = ( "test1", "test2", "test3" );
my @array2 = ( "test4", "test5", "test6" );
my @array3 = ( "test7", "test8", "test9" );
my %hashids = ( "1" => \@array1, "2" => \@array2, "3" => \@array3 );

my @targetarray1 = ( "test1", "test2", "test99" );
my @targetarray2 = ( "test4", "test6", "test100" );
my @targetarray3 = ( "test7", "test9", "test66" );
my %hashtarget_ids = ( "a" => \@targetarray1, "b" => \@targetarray2, "c" => \@targetarray3 );

my %finalhash;
my $i;
for my $itemarray ( values %hashids ) {
    for my $arrayval (@$itemarray) {
        for my $temp ( values %hashtarget_ids ) {
            for my $temp_text (@$temp) {
                if ( $arrayval eq $temp_text ) {
                    $i++;
                    my @final_array;
                    #print $hashtarget_ids[$$temp],"\n"; ##Print key value here as "a"
                    #print $hashids[$$temp],"\n"; ##Print key value here as "1"
                    #push @finalarray,$hashtarget_ids[$$temp]; ##Push key value to array
                    #push @finalarray,$hash_ids[$$temp]; ##Push key value to array
                    #%finalhash=("$i"=>\@final_array); ##Create hash
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are compilation errors in the script you've posted that need to be fixed first. If you run `perl -c <scriptname>`, perl will tell you what the errors are.

Comment: And see http://bioinfo2.ugr.es/documentation/Perl_Cookbook/ch05_12.htm

Comment: @i alarmed alien: I commented the part which throws error. I want to get the values as commented in the code

Comment: Why are you creating all those arrays instead of creating the hashes directly? And do you understand the difference between a hash and a reference to a hash?

Comment: @i alarmed alien: I came to know that only array reference can be passed to values in a hash and not arrays. Am i right? Also this is a part of my original coding. I am getting values and passing it through arrays, create array refernce to create hash values

Answer (score 3):

First a note.  To create an array as a value of a hash, you can use an anonymous array ref instead of creating a temporary array variable to later to take a references of:

```
$hash{key} = [ 'an', 'anonymous', 'array', 'ref' ];
```

Second, to find values that match between two arrays, check out: [How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the intersection of two arrays?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-compute-the-difference-of-two-arrays%3f-How-do-I-compute-the-intersection-of-two-arrays%3f)

I'm afraid that your overall goal is a little unclear.  If it's just to find element values that match between the two hashes, then all you need is a %seen style hash:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashids = (
    "1" => [ "test1", "test2", "test3" ],
    "2" => [ "test4", "test5", "test6" ],
    "3" => [ "test7", "test8", "test9" ]
);

my %hashtarget_ids = (
    "a" => [ "test1", "test2", "test99" ],
    "b" => [ "test4", "test6", "test100" ],
    "c" => [ "test7", "test9", "test66" ]
);

my %seen;
$seen{$_}++ for map {@$_} values %hashids;

my @final_array = sort grep {$seen{$_}} map {@$_} values %hashtarget_ids;

print "@final_array\n";
```

Outputs:

```
test1 test2 test4 test6 test7 test9
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have solved the issue by changing to array itself and have not used hashes.